# Code::Blocks How to specify SSDC debugger for PIC micro-controllers?

Tags: debugging, codeblocks, pic

I'm using SSDC Compiler for PIC micro-controllers, and it supposed to have a supported debugger called (SDCDB). Although, in compiler settings it shows Invalid Debugger in debugger option. So, how can I specify the SDCDB to be my default debugger. And, is there any problems using GDB with SDCC compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only answers part 1 of your question.  I don't know what happens when you use gdb with SDCC.

You will need to be an admin user for this

Look for **options_sdcc.xml** in **%programfiles%\CodeBlocks\share\CodeBlocks\compilers**

Open the file in an editor.  Look for DBGconfig on the windows platform.  Set the value to **sdcdb.exe**